# Оптимизировать добавление в таблицу в DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatable

Имеется ajax запрос который получает строку json c данными .Сам запрос выполняется быстро но отображение в таблице происходит когда цикл пройдет все записи А записей может быть более 12000 тыс .Как можно пока цикл еще проходит уже отображать данные

```
$.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type:'POST',
            url:'{{route('payment')}}',
            data: {startdate: startdate,enddate:enddate,service:service,terminal:terminal,status:status},

            success: function (response) {


                payments=response.payments;
                table
                    .clear()
                    .draw();
                var content ="";

               for(i=0; i<payments.length; i++) {

                    table.row.add(
                        [
                            payments[i].id,
                            payments[i].created_at,
                            payments[i].terminal,
                            payments[i].sumforpay,
                            payments[i].commission,
                            payments[i].dst,
                            payments[i].service,
                            payments[i].status,
                            '<a style="color: black"  href="/printcheck/'+payments[i].id+'">Печать чека</a>',

                            Math.abs( payments[i].difference),
                        ]
                    ).draw();





                }

all_pskts=response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission-response.paymentsinfo[0].sumpskts
                $('#all_pay').text("Всего платежей : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].count)
                $('#all_sum').text("На сумму : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].allsum)
                $('#all_com').text("Общая коммиссия : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission)
                $('#sumpskts').text("Сумма PSKTS : "+response.paymentsinfo[0].sumpskts)
                $('#all_sumpskts').text("Коммиссия : "+all_pskts)

                $(".lds-default").css("display", "none");

            },



        });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Вариант 1

Могу посоветовать вот такое решение, с использованием функции `forEachAsync`, которую я сделал на основании другого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344560/9921853) в Stack Overflow.

Для оптимизации можно поиграть с параметром maxTimePerChunk. В моей функции если он меньше или равен 20, то он показывает количество лупов перед высвобождением потока. Если больше 20, то это время в миллисекундах исполнения цикла перед высвобождением потока.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344560/9921853
// Loop over array in a non-blocking manner
var forEachAsync = function (array, fn, maxTimePerChunk, context) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        context = context || window;
        maxTimePerChunk = maxTimePerChunk || 100;
        var index = 0;

        //Number <=20 is a number of iterations per chunk
        if (maxTimePerChunk > 20) {
            function now() {
                return new Date().getTime();
            }

            function doTimedChunk() {
                //console.log("Async chunk by time. Index = " + index);
                var startTime = now();
                while (index < array.length && (now() - startTime) <= maxTimePerChunk) {
                    // callback called with args (value, index, array)
                    fn.call(context, array[index], index, array);
                    ++index;
                }
                if (index < array.length) {
                    // set Timeout for async iteration
                    setTimeout(doTimedChunk, 1);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
            doTimedChunk();
        } else {
            var nIterPerChunk = maxTimePerChunk;
            function doCountChunk() {
                //console.log("Async chunk by count. Index = " + index);
                var cnt = nIterPerChunk;
                while (cnt-- && index < array.length) {
                    // callback called with args (value, index, array)
                    fn.call(context, array[index], index, array);
                    ++index;
                }
                if (index < array.length) {
                    // set Timeout for async iteration
                    setTimeout(doCountChunk, 1);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
            doCountChunk();
        }
    });
}


$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{route('payment')}}',
    data: { startdate: startdate, enddate: enddate, service: service, terminal: terminal, status: status },

    success: async function (response) {

        payments = response.payments;
        table
            .clear()
            .draw();
        var content = "";

        await forEachAsync(payments, function (payment) {
            table.row.add(
                [
                    payment.id,
                    payment.created_at,
                    payment.terminal,
                    payment.sumforpay,
                    payment.commission,
                    payment.dst,
                    payment.service,
                    payment.status,
                    '<a style="color: black"  href="/printcheck/' + payment.id + '">Печать чека</a>',

                    Math.abs(payment.difference),
                ]
            ).draw();
        }, 10);

        all_pskts = response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission - response.paymentsinfo[0].sumpskts
        $('#all_pay').text("Всего платежей : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].count)
        $('#all_sum').text("На сумму : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].allsum)
        $('#all_com').text("Общая коммиссия : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission)
        $('#sumpskts').text("Сумма PSKTS : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].sumpskts)
        $('#all_sumpskts').text("Коммиссия : " + all_pskts)

        $(".lds-default").css("display", "none");

    },

});
```

### Вариант 2

Второй вариант несколько более упрощен в плане функционала и может быть даже медленнее, но решает важную проблему - в процессе заполнения таблицы Вы можете перемещаться по ней, используя Pagination.

Для этого пришлось применить "нечестный" прием с перехватом одной из функций отрисовки. Проблема в том, что Datatables отрисовывают панель Pagination при каждой команде draw, не зависимо от её параметров. При этом панель стирается и рисуется заново. Если изменения происходят быстро, то пользователь просто не успевает нажать на кнопки смены страницы - они исчезают раньше.

Решение - отрисовка панели Pagination только при изменениях текущей страницы или общего количества страниц. Можно было бы еще отслеживать изменения размера экрана, так как в этом случае тоже понадобится отрисовка по-новой. Но так как решение действует только пока добавляются данные, то этим можно пренебречь.

Есть ещё один недостаток - приходится вводить задержку, так как при слишком быстром заполнении данными - количество страниц тоже меняется быстро, и пользователь снова не успевает нажимать кнопки смены страницы...

Задержку можно подстраивать, либо можно вызывать draw не для каждой добавленной строки.

Исправленный код из вопроса - ниже. Смотрите также [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/e5swg07f/) с упрощенным рабочим примером.

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var oldPaginationCb;
var prevPage=-1, prevPages=-1;
var isCustomPaginationEnabled = false; //Our custom actions are disabled by default

function myPaginationCb ( settings ) {
  var
      start      = settings._iDisplayStart,
      len        = settings._iDisplayLength,
      visRecords = settings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
      all        = len === -1,
      page = all ? 0 : Math.ceil( start / len ),
      pages = all ? 1 : Math.ceil( visRecords / len );
  if (! (isCustomPaginationEnabled && page === prevPage && pages === prevPages)) {
      prevPage = page;
      prevPages = pages;
      return oldPaginationCb(settings);
  }
}


//Replacing the pagination draw callback function
var paginationCallback = table.fnSettings().aoDrawCallback.filter(cb => { return cb.sName === "pagination" })[0];
oldPaginationCb = paginationCallback.fn;
paginationCallback.fn = myPaginationCb;

$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{route('payment')}}',
    data: { startdate: startdate, enddate: enddate, service: service, terminal: terminal, status: status },

    success: async function (response) {

        payments = response.payments;
        table
            .clear()
            .draw();
        var content = "";

        isCustomPaginationEnabled = true;

        Array.prototype.forEach(payments, function (payment) {
            table.row.add(
                [
                    payment.id,
                    payment.created_at,
                    payment.terminal,
                    payment.sumforpay,
                    payment.commission,
                    payment.dst,
                    payment.service,
                    payment.status,
                    '<a style="color: black"  href="/printcheck/' + payment.id + '">Печать чека</a>',

                    Math.abs(payment.difference),
                ]
            ).draw(false);
            await sleep(50);
        });

        isCustomPaginationEnabled = false;

        all_pskts = response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission - response.paymentsinfo[0].sumpskts
        $('#all_pay').text("Всего платежей : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].count)
        $('#all_sum').text("На сумму : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].allsum)
        $('#all_com').text("Общая коммиссия : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].allcommission)
        $('#sumpskts').text("Сумма PSKTS : " + response.paymentsinfo[0].sumpskts)
        $('#all_sumpskts').text("Коммиссия : " + all_pskts)

        $(".lds-default").css("display", "none");

    },

});
```

Comment: Класс отображение теперь происходить.Но проблема остается по прежнему пока полностью не выполнеца  функция ,я не могу листать страницы меня постоянно перебрасывает на 1 страницу .

Comment: Используйте `.draw( false );`. [draw() manual](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

Comment: тогда он вообще не отображает данные в отчете

Comment: @АндрейКоваленко, посмотрите рабочий пример на JSFiddle, который я добавил для второго варианта ответа. Данные отображаются. И решена проблема с их перелистыванием

Comment: @АндрейКоваленко, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Comment: ну не совсем помог .Второй способ все ровно замедляет отображение.Если больше 600 станиц  с записями то он практически каждую секунду отрисовывает  а если больше то время растет .в мобильной версии вообще минуты 4 пока закончит отображать

Comment: @АндрейКоваленко Попробуйте использовать `deferRender` как [здесь](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html)